# Update to Illustrator 2023 - presets lost

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've just updated my Adobe Illustrator version to the 2023 version. Unfortunately by doing so I lost all my customized presets from the previous version
a) can I restore them?
b) what do I have to do to keep all presets when I am updating Illustrator next time? Can I save presets somewhere and import them later on?

Many thanks for your appreciated support!
Kind regards
Silvan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe traditionally installs a new version alongside any older versions. Your presets are still in the old Presets folder. On Mac, that's in Applications. I don't know for Windows.

[image]

Hmm, actually user presets are in the user library `~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop [year]/Presets/` not Applications. Win equivalent would probably be in `%localappdata%` instead.

Comment: Thank you! And how can I import all my settings (in one go)?

Comment: Hmm, actually user presets are in the user library `~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop 2020/Presets/` not Applications. Win equivalent would probably be in `%localappdata%` instead.

Comment: so i need to copy them to the Illustrator 2023 version folder?

Comment: Usually works just copying the whole folder over. Though to prevent issues it's probably best to just copy over where you made adjustments.